# Sonar maven plugin - never ending for Java file > 100 kb

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

We are using Sonar maven plugin to analyze our Java projects.

SonarQube V4.0
Sonar maven plugin V2.2

Our test profile is a copy of the Sonarway Java profile with just 1 rule enabled - which checks for System.out and System.err in .java files.

All of our projects are analyzed, but two files seem to be continuously analyzed and sonar keeps on running forever for those. The file sizes are 111kb and 121kb.

After setting the sonar exclusions for these files, Sonar analysis completed within few minutes. When these larges files were included in the Sonar run, sonar maven plugin was running for over 1 hour on these files before we manually aborted it.

Any configuration required to let sonar analyze large files ?
Any limitations on file size that can be analyzed by Sonar ?

Comment: Here was the answer given to this question: http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/Sonar-maven-plugin-never-ending-for-Java-file-gt-100-kb-td5020713.html

Comment: I too get error when the file size is more than around 45 Kb. It gives error related to some pointer.